# Inequality that may use Simon's Favorite Factoring Trick

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c,d,e$ be positive integers.
When is $abcd>abc+abd+acd+bcd+ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd+a+b+c+d$?
Additionally, when is $abcde>abcd+abce+...a+b+c+d+e$?

Comment: I don't know how widely "Simon's Favorite Factoring Trick" is known. Personally, I haven't heard of this name before, but google search leads to [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Simon's_Favorite_Factoring_Trick). (Just adding this in case others haven't heard of SFFT).

Comment: I guess you are asking for simpler but equivalent forms for the inequalities you have written.  Not sure if it is simpler, but I find $$(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)(d-1) > 2(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd)+1$$ marginally better for the first one.  In particular, trivially it shows you need all the integers to be higher than $1$.